# On page load default value not showing in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have five radio button and as per the five different values of radio button, five span tags are generated with the description on this radio button like below:

```
<table class="jshop">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="attributes_title">
            <span class="attributes_name">Model:</span><span class="attributes_description"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="block_attr_sel_3">
            <span class="input_type_radio">
                <input type="radio" name="jshop_attr_id[3]" id="jshop_attr_id35" value="5" checked="true" onclick="setAttrValue('3', this.value);"> 
                <label for="jshop_attr_id35"><span class="radio_attr_label">16 GB</span></label>
            </span>
            <span class="input_type_radio">
                <input type="radio" name="jshop_attr_id[3]" id="jshop_attr_id36" value="6" onclick="setAttrValue('3', this.value);"> 
                <label for="jshop_attr_id36"><span class="radio_attr_label">32 GB</span></label></span>                
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="attributes_title">
            <span class="attributes_name">What Type?:</span><span class="attributes_description"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="block_attr_sel_5">
            <span class="input_type_radio">
                <input type="radio" name="jshop_attr_id[5]" id="jshop_attr_id59" value="9" checked="true" onclick="setAttrValue('5', this.value);"> 
                <label for="jshop_attr_id59"><span class="radio_attr_label">Broken</span></label>
            </span>
            <span class="input_type_radio">
                <input type="radio" name="jshop_attr_id[5]" id="jshop_attr_id510" value="10" onclick="setAttrValue('5', this.value);"> 
                <label for="jshop_attr_id510"><span class="radio_attr_label">Good</span></label>
           </span>
           <span class="input_type_radio">
               <input type="radio" name="jshop_attr_id[5]" id="jshop_attr_id511" value="11" onclick="setAttrValue('5', this.value);"> 
               <label for="jshop_attr_id511"><span class="radio_attr_label">Flawless</span></label></span>                
           </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<span id="attr_5" class="attr_desc"></span>
<span id="attr_6" class="attr_desc"></span>
<span id="attr_9" class="attr_desc">test1</span>
<span id="attr_10" class="attr_desc">test2</span>
<span id="attr_11" class="attr_desc">test3</span>
```

Now I want that whenever user select one of the radio button from above, related description will show . So i tried like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".input_type_radio input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        jQuery(".attr_desc").hide();
        var test = jQuery(this).val();

        jQuery("#attr_" + test).show();
    });
    jQuery(".attr_desc").hide();
});
</script>
```

and it is working perfectly but my problem is whenever the page loaded , no description will be shown ,even by default there are two values already selected ,I don't know why its not working. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is becuase your are showing/hiding the correspoding span only in change event ... you need to check the checked value in document.ready and show/hide likewise

try this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

     jQuery(".input_type_radio input[type=radio]").change(function() {
     ..... //your code
     });
     jQuery(".input_type_radio input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(){
      jQuery("#attr_" + $(this).val()).show();
    });

});
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/b5Ey2/)

Answer (score 0):

So, before binding change event, just check for the existing values of the radio buttons and hide/display the description accordingly. Currently, you are simply hiding all descriptions by default

Comment: This should be in comment.

Comment: How to check for the existing values of the radio buttons checked?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to this style:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".input_type_radio input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        showDesc();
    });

    function showDesc() {
        jQuery(".attr_desc").hide();
        var test = jQuery(".input_type_radio input[type=radio]:checked").val();
        jQuery("#attr_" + test).show();
    }
    showDesc();
});
```